# Training a neural network to play Rock Paper Scissors, gets stuck in a single reply

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

**Background**: I am trying to teach a neural network to play rock-paper-scissors against 4 different bots, to solve a task for a coding course (freecodecamp.com) Each bot is a pre-determined strategy, and some are more complex than others. I'm a beginner in neural networks and I'm trying to become self-taught. I'm having problems creating a network that defeats the strongest of them all. I've tried to follow instructions mainly from the course and also from this blog entry by Svilen Todorov https://svilentodorov.xyz/blog/rps/

**The problem**: I'm trying to create a neural network that "defeats" the following bot:

```
def abbey(prev_opponent_play,
          opponent_history=[],
          play_order=[{
              "RR": 0,
              "RP": 0,
              "RS": 0,
              "PR": 0,
              "PP": 0,
              "PS": 0,
              "SR": 0,
              "SP": 0,
              "SS": 0,
          }]):

    if not prev_opponent_play:
        prev_opponent_play = 'R'
    opponent_history.append(prev_opponent_play)

    last_two = "".join(opponent_history[-2:])
    if len(last_two) == 2:
        play_order[0][last_two] += 1

    potential_plays = [
        prev_opponent_play + "R",
        prev_opponent_play + "P",
        prev_opponent_play + "S",
    ]

    sub_order = {
        k: play_order[0][k]
        for k in potential_plays if k in play_order[0]
    }

    prediction = max(sub_order, key=sub_order.get)[-1:]

    ideal_response = {'P': 'S', 'R': 'P', 'S': 'R'}
    return ideal_response[prediction]
```

As you can see, the bot is deterministic (no randomness) but capable of a varied response to the opponent's "history".

**Attempted solution** The first thing I did was obtain a large (n=2000) dataset of games where random moves were played against "Abby". After that, trained my neural network on that data, but couldn't reach a high (>80%) accuracy using 10 epochs. I decided not to use more epochs, but rather to fight this new version of the neural network to fight Abby, then obtain that data, and re-feed it into the neural network, as to try and "update" its database. For some reason, every time I updated it, the result was that the neural network got stuck into a loop after a few plays, sometimes from the outset, and of course the bot beat it. Sometimes it was a 1-play loop (R - R - R - R etc) sometimes it was 2 or 3-play loops (P - S - R - P - S - R - P etc)

This is the code for the neural network:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from dataManipulation import open_csv
import numpy as np
import csv

TRAINING_ITER = 0   # If at 0, check the file_path manually

UPDATING = True
RESET_STATES = True

NUM_GAMES = 20000
SEQ_LENGTH = 10  # I can feel this is going to be tricky. We are back to len 10.
TRAINING = True
DENSE_NEURONS = 24
RNN_UNITS = 512
EPOCH_NUM = 2


if TRAINING_ITER == 0:
    file_path = "db_random_n20000.csv"
else:
    file_path = f'./databases/abbey/db1_nn_abbey_n{NUM_GAMES}_0{TRAINING_ITER-1}.csv'  # Raw data
load_chk_path = f'./checkpoints/abbey/trained{TRAINING_ITER-1}'
last_saved_chk_path = f'./checkpoints/abbey/trained{TRAINING_ITER}'

# OHE the data
move_to_ohe = {  # Create a dictionary to OHE the data
    "R": [1, 0, 0],
    "P": [0, 1, 0],
    "S": [0, 0, 1],
}


def build_model(seq_l, vocab_size, rnn_units, dense_neurons):
    this_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(seq_l, vocab_size), dtype='int32'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(dense_neurons, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(rnn_units,
                             return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
    ])
    return this_model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Import the data
    raw_data = open_csv(file_path)
    data = np.array([[move_to_ohe[val] for val in row] for row in raw_data])  
    # Next, we need to sequence the data, since the model won't operate on single-move games, nor on games like Todorov's
    total_seqs = len(data) - (SEQ_LENGTH + 1)

    # Creating the training sequences
    Xy1_sequences = np.empty((total_seqs, SEQ_LENGTH + 1, 2, 3), dtype=int)
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        if i == total_seqs:
            break
        Xy1_sequences[i] = data[i: i + (SEQ_LENGTH + 1)]
    x1_seq = Xy1_sequences[:, :-1, :, :]
    y1_seq = Xy1_sequences[:, 1:, 0, :]  # y1 has to be only about the opponent        

    x1_seq, y1_seq = np.reshape(x1_seq, (total_seqs, SEQ_LENGTH, 6)), \
        np.reshape(y1_seq, (total_seqs, SEQ_LENGTH, 3))


    # I'll try building the model following Russica, since Todorov's method is not working.

    model = build_model(SEQ_LENGTH, 6, RNN_UNITS, DENSE_NEURONS)
    print("Database len: ", len(x1_seq))

    if TRAINING:
        model.summary()
        opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
        if UPDATING:
            if TRAINING_ITER != 0:
                model.load_weights(load_chk_path).expect_partial()
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(x1_seq, y1_seq, epochs=EPOCH_NUM, shuffle=False, batch_size=8, verbose=2)

        # Save the weights
        model.save_weights(last_saved_chk_path)
        print("Iteration number ", TRAINING_ITER)
        print("Weights saved to ", last_saved_chk_path)
    else:
        model.load_weights(load_chk_path).expect_partial()  # We are OK with working with weights only. This silences warnings.
        model.summary()
```

While this code contains the "player", a function that defines a response to the bot, and that is used in another "Play" function. I didn't write the Play function, it was incorporated in the task.

I have the feeling that I'm doing something wrong with the loss function, but I don't know what could it be.

To make matters more complicated, I already used this code to beat a simpler bot:

```
def quincy(prev_play, counter=[0]):
    counter[0] += 1
    choices = ["R", "R", "P", "P", "S"]
    return choices[counter[0] % len(choices)]
```

So I don't think there's a bug in the code itself (that is, the Neural Network can at least recognize the patterns, and there doesn't seem to be any errors in encoding that might be causing a wrong result) I don't know if I'm doing something wrong while building my model, if I'm choosing the wrong layers, or if there is some sort of hyperparameter I'm not taking into consideration. I have changed:

The # of epochs

The activation functions for all layers

The number of neurons for all layers

Updating the model or just using the new dataset, when iterating the model.

Stateful LSTM on or off

Reset state of the model before every play

Comment: Did you try validating the model against an unseen split of data (test split)? If yes, what was the loss and accuracy on the test dataset. As a tip, you can also experiment with 1D convolutional layers as they work pretty well in capturing temporal patterns within data.

Comment: I haven't tried a test split, I'll get working on it, but in the first iteration, the model almost always has bad numbers. At 2 epochs it hits 0.63 loss and at 20 epochs 0.21 loss (the 2nd iteration is fighting this model against the bot, and using that history to re-train the model)

Comment: I will try using a 1D conv layer and I'll report my findings. Thank you.